# Error in running html files in the localhost

Tags: gruntjs, localhost

I have started a HTTP server with grunt. I can visit the index.html when I type "http://localhost:1337/dist/templates".
I have one other html page that wanted to open in the localhost which is "about.html". When I type `"http://localhost:1337/dist/templates/about.html"`, it still shows me the index.html page.
I am wondering where my mistake is ?